# USB Stick doesn't react after 'formatting'

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount

I'm writing this thread because i haven't found any solution yet. The problem is that after formatting my USB stick 2 days ago(`sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1`) from FAT to NTFS to get rid of 4 GB file limit.It's a 32 GB USB stick from Toshiba. Everything seemed to be okay until the reboot. Since then i can't access it because it doesn't react to plug.I tried various things but still the same.On windows 10 however i can see F drive but can't access it either.

Output of some commands:

```
lsusb
```

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0c76:0005 JMTek, LLC. Transcend Flash disk
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 09da:000a A4Tech Co., Ltd. Optical Mouse Opto 510D / OP-620D
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

```
dmesg | tail -n10

[11631.572258] [UFW AUDIT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:25:22:8c:c7:a0:08:10:78:23:75:aa:08:00 SRC=151.101.1.69 DST=192.168.1.3 LEN=1496 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=20787 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=48938 WINDOW=300 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[11631.572303] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.3 DST=151.101.1.69 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=55410 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=48938 DPT=443 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[11631.572480] [UFW AUDIT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:25:22:8c:c7:a0:08:10:78:23:75:aa:08:00 SRC=151.101.1.69 DST=192.168.1.3 LEN=1396 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=20788 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=48938 WINDOW=300 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[11631.572499] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.3 DST=151.101.1.69 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=55411 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=48938 DPT=443 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[11631.572719] [UFW AUDIT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:25:22:8c:c7:a0:08:10:78:23:75:aa:08:00 SRC=151.101.1.69 DST=192.168.1.3 LEN=1496 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=20789 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=48938 WINDOW=300 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[11631.572737] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.3 DST=151.101.1.69 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=55412 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=48938 DPT=443 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[11631.573826] [UFW AUDIT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:25:22:8c:c7:a0:08:10:78:23:75:aa:08:00 SRC=151.101.1.69 DST=192.168.1.3 LEN=1286 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=20790 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=48938 WINDOW=300 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[11631.573851] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.3 DST=151.101.1.69 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=55413 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=48938 DPT=443 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[11631.765579] [UFW AUDIT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:25:22:8c:c7:a0:08:10:78:23:75:aa:08:00 SRC=151.101.1.69 DST=192.168.1.3 LEN=564 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=2825 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=48937 WINDOW=237 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[11631.765610] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.1.3 DST=151.101.1.69 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=5726 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=48937 DPT=443 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

```
cat /etc/mtab
```

```
/dev/sda5 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755 0 0
none /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
overflow /tmp tmpfs rw,size=1048576,mode=1777 0 0
/dev/sda7 /home ext4 rw 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd 0 0
/home/boss/.Private /home/boss ecryptfs ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=19ba0418664290d3,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=5cd3a2573947e2d1 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,user=boss 0 0
```

```
ls /dev/ | grep sd
```

```
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sda4
sda5
sda6
sda7
sdb
```

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

```
tail: cannot open ‘/var/log/messages’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

```
lsmod | grep usb
```

```
usb_storage            62209  0 
usbhid                 52659  0 
hid                   106148  3 hid_a4tech,hid_generic,usbhid
```

```
df -h
```

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                 2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                396M  1.3M  394M   1% /run
/dev/sda5             28G   20G  6.5G  76% /
none                 4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                 2.0G   62M  1.9G   4% /run/shm
none                 100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
overflow             1.0M   16K 1008K   2% /tmp
/dev/sda7            613G  185G  397G  32% /home
/home/boss/.Private  613G  185G  397G  32% /home/boss
```

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
135 heads, 14 sectors/track, 1033611 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf7bd90fe

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   585222747   292507950    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       585224192   586143743      459776   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda4       586145790  1953523711   683688961    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       586145792   644739071    29296640   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       644741120   648644607     1951744   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       648646656  1953523711   652438528   83  Linux
```

```
lsblk
```

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   279G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   449M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0    28G  0 part /
├─sda6   8:6    0   1.9G  0 part 
└─sda7   8:7    0 622.2G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I'm sorry for that spam but i couldn't find spoiler option. I need some help from you ASAP. It's weird that fdisk and df can't see it.It's quite tough problem for me.

I look forward to hearing from you,

SuperDude

***edit1 :***

after that 'sudo ntfsfix -b /dev/sdb' i got

```
'Mounting volume... Error opening '/dev/sdb': No medium found
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Error opening '/dev/sdb': No medium found
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No medium found
Error opening '/dev/sdb': No medium found
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk. '
```

and after sudo fsck /dev/sdb i got this :

```
'fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
fsck.ext2: No medium found while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768  '
```

tried that e2fsck but it changed nothing

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
fsck.ext2: No medium found while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768
```

Comment: Once I'd had similar problem, but don't remember what the cause (it seems was a windows bootable pendrive). I solved it with gparted: I'd deleted all partitions and applied the changes.  Then I'd created a new single partition NTFS. I don't know xubuntu has gparted but I believe has something native similar software.

Comment: About gparted i have it installed but it only sees my HDD partitions , nothing else.

Comment: Ok, @SuperDude. On gparted screen in device selector (up-rigth corner) Isn't there the pendrive device?? Could you try in other USB port? Or in other linux machine?

Comment: I can choose only /dev/sda (931.51GB). I own other 16GB usb stick but it works fine. About the other ports i checked all and the same situation. I only have one PC right now so just xubuntu and win10 on dual boot.

Comment: Now I remember. I'd this problem because one partition was bootable and encrypted.  Have you created any encrypted/bootable partition before? If has been the case, try to delete with the same program. These partition are visible only to these programs.

Comment: Unfornately i tried to format it only via terminal by mkfs.ntfs to make it blank. I think something could gone wrong but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Could you try this: open a "root terminal", runs gparted and try to access the device?

Comment: gparted runs only via root 'Root privileges are required for running gparted.' but still cant see other devices than my hdd. It looks like this usb stick is broken or something because it's not blinking but 2 days ago it was fine.

Comment: This [app ntfsfix](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix) could save you. You could try also gparted from live cd. Almost 90% sure you can solve by one of these ways.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try it. I just checked it in windows 10 but still cant open. I mean i can see it but it says that it isn't plugged. I tried to find in regedit too but there's too many 'usb mass storage'

Comment: In windows use easeUS. I beleive it could  destoy your ghost partition.    If [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions)  doesn't solve better you buy another pendrive and anymore format them by command line @SuperdDude ;)

Comment: thanks, it was very comforting . So it's dead... (oh this post about dead usb stick disappeared)

Comment: Not solved???? Oh, sorry, post these things sured you will! Really weird. Maybe for some reason, your partition is on unknown format. Now the last attempt, try [easeUs](http://easeus.com/). It recognize several format types. If It doesn't work, I really don't know how can I help you.

Comment: Now, see your update1.  I suggest you submit this case to [ubuntu bugs launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net) and manufacturer, I believe it's important they became awared of this situation.

Comment: Sorry i was trying to solve this problem that i forgot about anything other.I downloaded easyUS but like Gparted it can't see my usb drive,only hdd. If i only could detect this device i could just mount it manually...

Comment: Ok I will report it there and think about other solutions. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Oh, so sorry you hasn't success @SuperDude. I'm curious about this issue, It's news to me a simple command cause the destruction of the device. This is the advantage of format by interface, I believe filters some commands. Well, good luck on bug reports and if possible, share the results here.

Comment: Could you pogst the output of `dmesg | grep usb` just after you plug the flash.